# Can I define the region Google Cloud Container Builder runs in?

Tags: google-container-registry, google-container-builder

My Google Cloud Container Builder steps are touching information that should not leave the European Union. Is it possible to restrict the region for a build so that it won't be executed in `us-central1` for example?

I know I can [define the region, where the resulting images are stored](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling), but that does not mean the processing happens within the EU, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot at this time define the region where the processing happens. However, since all processing of your build is ephemeral, data lives in the arbitrarily-selected processing region only for the brief lifetime of your build.

If you believe you need more control over regionality than this ephemeral lifespan offers, please make this a formal feature request by sending details regarding your use case to gcr-contact@google.com.

Comment: Thank you, I've just sent a formal feature request to the mentioned e-mail address.